# twilio error - message.json was not found

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I need some help with twilio API.
I'm using php, I need to send an sms with the RESTFUL API.

[I have follow this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest)

First I get an error with ssl. I need to disable the ssl checker.
Then I get this error msg :

> Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The requested resource
>   /2010-04-01/Accounts/ibmblue/Messages.json was not found

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

For your SSL issue, disabling the SSL checker is likely the wrong solution. There are some [ways to fix SSL issues](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions) here.

As for the other issue, I can see within the URL that is causing a 404 that you have used the Account SID `ibmblue`. That doesn't look like an Account SID to me. You need to find your Account SID on your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console). It should be listed underneath the title "Account summary" and start "AC...". Ensure you have your Account SID set correctly and your API calls should start to work.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for that
1: you have not created the Messaging Service Id (SID) in Twilio. so make sure to create the SID
2: Make sure to use the same SID in the code that you have create in Twilio account.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32111429)